# ion-tabs displaying, but not switching to other tabs

Tags: ionic-framework

I couldn't find a question that helps me.

I've this on every one of my pages. The navbar is displaying, but the buttons aren't switching to other tabs. This is quite literally copied from the `ionic start myApp tabs`.

This is one of the pages:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Playlists</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>

<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="saved">
            <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Saved</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="search">
            <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Search</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="playlists">
            <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Playlists</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

And this is my `app-routing.modules.ts` file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'saved', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'saved', loadChildren: './pages/saved/saved.module#SavedPageModule' },
  { path: 'search', loadChildren: './pages/search/search.module#SearchPageModule' },
  { path: 'playlists', loadChildren: './pages/playlists/playlists.module#PlaylistsPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went with the default tabs template again, you need a tabs router. I hadn't made any progress so it's fine.